# Dojo deferred retry until success

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a method in my dojo class which makes a request (say, a JSON one). If it succeeds, well and good. However, if it fails (times out or whatever), I want it to try again until it succeeds. To do this, I call the method itself in the error callback:

```
doReq: function(){
    var req = Request(...);
    return req.then(function(response, io){
        // Success!
    }, dojo.hitch(this, function(error, io){
        this.doReq(); // Failed; try again.
    }));
}
```

Am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done this way, but you may want to limit attempts,

for example:

```
doReq: function(attempts){
    attempts -= 1;
    var req = Request(...);
    return req.then(function(response, io){
        // Success!
    }, dojo.hitch(this, function(error, io){
        if (attempts > 0) this.doReq(attempts); // Failed; try again.
        else //return some error here
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you return `req.then(...)`, this will return new promise not the `req`'s promise.

But if you want the caller of `doReq` to get response when the `req` succeeds, you can do it like this.

```
_request: function (deferred) {
    var req = Request(...);
    req.then(dojo.hitch(this, function (response, io) {
        // Success!
        deferred.resolve(response);
    }), dojo.hitch(this, function (error, io) {
        this._request(deferred); // Failed; try again.
        // use deferred.reject('some error message'); to reject when it reached the retry limit, if you want to.
    }));
}, 
doReq: function () {
    var deferred = new Deferred(); // from module "dojo/Deferred"
    this._request(deferred);
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

This is how to use it.

```
var thePromise = this.doReq();
thePromise.then(dojo.hitch(this, function (response) {
    console.log('response: ', response); // your response from deferred.resolve(response);
}), dojo.hitch(this, function (error) {
    console.log('error: ', error); // your error from deferred.reject('some error message'); if you have.
}));
```